# 3d Contour Plotting

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot three 3D-contour plots in the region $x,y,z >=0$ and $x+y+z<1.$ The functions which I would like to plot are as follows

```
 r = 0.4;
a1 = 2; a2 = 3; a3 = 4; \
v1 = 0.2; v2 = 0.3; v3 = 0.4;      (*a1,a2,a3, v1,v2,v3 are \
parameters such that ai\[GreaterEqual] 0 and vi>0 and v1+v2+v3<1*)

f1[x_, y_, 
   z_] = ((1 - r) a1*
     x/(1 + (a1 - 1)*x + (a2 - 1)*y + (a3 - 1)*z)) + r*v1 - x;
f2[x_, y_, 
   z_] = ((1 - r) a2*
     y/(1 + (a1 - 1)*x + (a2 - 1)*y + (a3 - 1)*z)) + r*v2 - y;
f3[x_, y_, 
   z_] = ((1 - r) a3*
     x/(1 + (a1 - 1)*x + (a2 - 1)*y + (a3 - 1)*z)) + r*v3 - z;
```

I would like to see the above three functions on the same 3d plot in the region $x,y,z >=0$ and $x+y+z<1.$ I tried using ContourPlot3d but it did not work for me (most probably because am not using it correctly). Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[{f1[x, y, z], f2[x, y, z], f3[x, y, z]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 
  0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y + z < 1], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]`

Answer (score 1):

```
r = 0.4;
a1 = 2; a2 = 3; a3 = 4; v1 = 0.2; v2 = 0.3; v3 = 0.4;
f1[x_, y_, 
   z_] := ((1 - r) a1*x/(1 + (a1 - 1)*x + (a2 - 1)*y + (a3 - 1)*z)) + 
   r*v1 - x;
f2[x_, y_, 
   z_] := ((1 - r) a2*y/(1 + (a1 - 1)*x + (a2 - 1)*y + (a3 - 1)*z)) + 
   r*v2 - y;
f3[x_, y_, 
   z_] := ((1 - r) a3*x/(1 + (a1 - 1)*x + (a2 - 1)*y + (a3 - 1)*z)) + 
   r*v3 - z;

ContourPlot3D[{f1[x, y, z], f2[x, y, z], 
  f3[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x + y + z < 1, {x, y, z}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this message. "ContourPlot3D::pllim: Range specification {x,y,z}\[Element]ImplicitRegion[x>0&&y>0&&z>0&&x+y+z<1,{x,y,z}] is not of the form {x, xmin, xmax}." I have Mathematica 11.1.1 version

Comment: Is it possible to remove the space and just have the entire plot in the $x+y+z <=1$ and $x,y,z>=0$ region ?

Comment: To be sure, I copied my own code from this page and (once again) ran it with a fresh kernel on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 and got the same image. I am not aware of the trick to remove the region box shown in gray. Add this info to main question if you cannot run this. It may be version related.